# DataSet.ReadXml - Error “input string was not in a correct format”

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset

There are two inputs to the code

1. XML file
2. XSD file

XML content

```
<MyFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Attribute>
      <AttributeName>Text1</AttributeName>
      <AttributeContent>1</AttributeContent>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute>
      <AttributeName>Text1</AttributeName>
      <AttributeContent>1</AttributeContent>
  </Attribute>
</MyFile>
```

XSD content corresponding to this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MyFile">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Attribute">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AttributeName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AttributeContent" type="xs:decimal" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

To read XML file in C#, I am using

```
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXmlSchema(new MemoryStream(xmlSourceModel.File2Content));

            foreach (DataTable tab in ds.Tables)
            {
                tab.BeginLoadData();
            }
            ds.ReadXml(new MemoryStream(xmlSourceModel.File1Content));

            foreach (DataTable tab in ds.Tables)
            {
                tab.EndLoadData(); 
            }
```

After this, I am expecting data in the dataset. And it does work.

**Problem:**
If I use XML content like following

```
 <Attribute>
      <AttributeName>Text1</AttributeName>
      <AttributeContent></AttributeContent>
  </Attribute>
```

Note here AttributeContent does not contain the value.

In this case `ds.ReadXml()` method give error
***"Input string was not in a correct format."***

How can we resolve this error so that we can pick null data?

or

Can we put some default data to avoid this error?

Comment: your AttributeContent element is of the type decimal and cannot be left empty. if you do not wish to fill the element you need to skip it. That is allowed because you defined it as minoccurs = 0

Comment: @martijn I have added minoccurs=0 in the XSD, It still shows the same error.

Comment: yes you still get the error as you need to remove the attributecontent from the message to get it validated. the minoccurs=0 allows you to leave the <attributecontent></attributecontent> out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the XML file is now correct in this case.

**Solution 1.** Do not add the attribute which does not contain the value

```
<Attribute>
      <AttributeName>Text1</AttributeName>
  </Attribute>
```

**Solution 2,** Add xsi:nil="true" something like this

```
 <Attribute>
      <AttributeName>Text1</AttributeName>
      <AttributeContent xsi:nil="true"></AttributeContent>
  </Attribute>
```